# Краш приложения при добавлении данных в таблицу SQLite

Tags: java, android, android-studio, sqlite

```
public void startTimer(View v) {

    DayDbHelper dayDbHelper = new DayDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dayDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DayContract.TrenOnDay.COLUMN_DATE, date);
    values.put(DayContract.TrenOnDay.COLUMN_YPRN, getYpr);
    values.put(DayContract.TrenOnDay.COLUMN_POD, stringP);
    values.put(DayContract.TrenOnDay.COLUMN_POV, kolPov);
    values.put(DayContract.TrenOnDay.COLUMN_VES, getVes);

    long newRowId = db.insert(DayContract.TrenOnDay.TABLE_NAME, null, values);

    if (newRowId == -1) {
        Toast toastErrorbd = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Ошибка записи прогресса", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toastErrorbd.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        toastErrorbd.show();
    } else {
        Toast toastSuc = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Прогресс сохранен", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toastSuc.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        toastSuc.show();

    }
```

Добавляю данные в таблицу методом onClick

Контракт:

```
public final class DayContract {

    private DayContract(){

    };


    public static final class TrenOnDay implements BaseColumns{

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "table";
        public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
        public static final String COLUMN_YPRN = "ypr";
        public static final String COLUMN_POD = "pod";
        public static final String COLUMN_POV = "pov";
        public static final String COLUMN_VES = "ves";
        public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;

    }
```

Хелпер

```
public class DayDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = DayDbHelper.class.getSimpleName();
    private static final String DB_NAME = "myTren.db";
    private static final int DB_V = 1;

    public DayDbHelper (Context context){

        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_V);
    }

    public void onCreate (SQLiteDatabase db){

        String SQL_CREATE_DAY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + DayContract.TrenOnDay.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                DayContract.TrenOnDay._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                DayContract.TrenOnDay.COLUMN_DATE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                DayContract.TrenOnDay.COLUMN_YPRN + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                DayContract.TrenOnDay.COLUMN_POD + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                DayContract.TrenOnDay.COLUMN_POV + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                DayContract.TrenOnDay.COLUMN_VES + " TEXT NOT NULL);";
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_DAY_TABLE);

    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        Log.w("SQLite", "Обновляемся с версии " + oldVersion + " на версию " + newVersion);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DayContract.TrenOnDay.TABLE_NAME);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

Это?

```
11-11 20:25:47.821 18111-18111/aranea.upnotealfa I/ViewRootImpl: CPU Rendering VSync enable = true
11-11 20:25:47.964 18111-18111/aranea.upnotealfa I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@2d05930f time:83453699
11-11 20:25:55.779 18111-18111/aranea.upnotealfa E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "TABLEtable": syntax error
```

Comment: прикрепите лог ошибки

Comment: @SviatVolkov прикрепил

Comment: под логом я имел ввиду стектрейс ошибки) когда приложение падает, то в Logcat выводится стектрейс. запускайте приложение под дебагом

Comment: @SviatVolkov посмотри, это?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"TABLEtable": syntax error - а вот и проблема.

```
String SQL_CREATE_DAY_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE" + DayContract.TrenOnDay.TABLE_NAME
```

Ошибка тут. После CREATE TABLE добавьте пробел. `"CREATE TABLE "`

Answer (score 2):

У вас не хватает пробела между `CREATE TABLE` и собственно именем таблицы